# get the number from a string then do the calculation

Tags: php

I have a string like this

```
$coordinate = "coords='429, 457, 421, 460, 424, 464, 433, 465, 433, 460'";
```

I want to multiply the numbers by 2, how can write a simple php code the do the calculation for this?

This new $coordinate should be

```
coords="858, 914, 842, 920, 848, 928, 866, 930, 866, 920"
```

My orriginal string is `"alt='Japan' shape='poly' coords='429, 457, 421, 460, 424, 464, 433, 465, 433, 460'";`

Comment: explode in to array, then loop

Comment: I don't think that will even interpret correctly.  Doesn't the string end with the equals sign as you've written it?

Comment: The result should be like this,
$coordinate = "coords="858, 914, 842, 920, 848, 928, 866, 930, 866, 920"";

"coords=" is the string

Comment: That's not even valid syntax: `$coordinate = "coords="429, 457, 421, 460, 424, 464, 433, 465, 433, 460"";`

Answer (score 3):

something like:

```
$coords="429, 457, 421, 460, 424, 464, 433, 465, 433, 460";
$coords_arr = explode(",", $coords);
array_walk($coords_arr, 'alter');

function alter(&$val) {
    $val *= 2; //multiply by 2
}
print_r($coords_arr);
```

updated code::

```
$coordinate = "coords='429, 457, 421, 460, 424, 464, 433, 465, 433, 460'";
$arr = explode("=", $coordinate);
$data = trim($arr[1], "'"); //remove quotes from start and end
$coords=explode(",", $data);

array_walk($coords, 'alter');

function alter(&$val) {
    $val = (int) $val * 2;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($coords);
```

Comment: you are jumping some steps, how do you get $coords = "429, 457, 421, 460, 424, 464, 433, 465, 433, 460"; ?

Comment: @alexalex added complete code

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you original array is defined as

```
 $coords="429, 457, 421, 460, 424, 464, 433, 465, 433, 460";
```

You can do this with [explode](http://www.php.net/explode), [array_map](http://www.php.net/array_map) and [implode](http://www.php.net/implode). Note that the anonymous function used here will only work for php 5.3 and above.

```
$newCoords = implode(", ",array_map(function($a) { return $a *2; }, explode(",", $coords)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Working code from your example above... Note changes in quote from " to '

```
$coordinate = 'coords="429, 457, 421, 460, 424, 464, 433, 465, 433, 460"';

$start = strpos($coordinate,'"');
$end = strrpos($coordinate,'"');

$str = substr($coordinate,$start + 1, ($end - $start -1));

$val_a = explode(', ',$str);

$new_str = '';
foreach ($val_a as $val_1) {
    $val_i = (int)$val_1 * 2;
    if ($new_str) $new_str .= ", $val_i";
    else $new_str = "$val_i";
}

echo 'coords="'.$new_str.'"';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first strip out all unwanted text then call array_map like this:

```
$coordinate = "coords=\"429, 457, 421, 460, 424, 464, 433, 465, 433, 460\"";
$s = preg_replace('/coords\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/', '$1', $coordinate);
$coordinate = 'coords="' . implode(", ", array_map(function($n) {return $n*2;}, 
               explode(",", $s))) . '"';
echo $coordinate . "\n";
//=> coords="858, 914, 842, 920, 848, 928, 866, 930, 866, 920"
```